# Is it possible to access someone else's C:/ drive?

Tags: local-storage

Last week I did work on someone else's computer because they were away for a week and well, they have two monitors (which are both bigger than my one) and a better computer config and it was convenitent because it meant the boss could talk to me when they needed me. I saved all my work in a folder called 'Trey' and forgot to email it's contents on the last day, is there a way to get access without logging on etc. and don't say 'can't he just email it over?'

Any help would be much appreciated,

Trey

Comment: you are essentially asking, how to hack into his computer without his knowledge?

Comment: Talk to the IT administrators at your work.

Comment: @Lawrence I am the assistant IT admim

Comment: Why not just ask the computer's owner to copy it to your computer ?

Comment: Because he doesn't get in for a little while and it needs to be done like, well near enough to now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the setup, it could be as easy as accessing it via the UNC path, assuming you have access.
`\\pcname\C$\trey`

Comment: of course! That seems so obvious now! Thank you!

Comment: if you have access I agree this is the way to